# Jquery append a form input with defined value and name

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am setting up a Blueimp gallery for Bootstrap that shows the photos from a Flickr photoset, adapting the provided jquery. How to append a form input to each thumbnail? The input must have a defined name and a value equal to the javascript value **photo.Title**. Despite much googling, at present I can only append an input with the value but no name, or with name but no value.

The code, with the penultimate line not working:-

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
            photoset_id: 'etc',
            user_id: 'etc',
            api_key: 'etc'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
    }).done(function (result) {
        var linksContainer = $('#links'),
            baseUrl;
        // Add the demo images as links with thumbnails to the page:
        $.each(result.photos.photo, function (index, photo) {
            baseUrl = 'https://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
                photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret;
            $('<a/>')
                .append($('<img>').prop('src', baseUrl + '_s.jpg'))
                .append("<span><input type='text' name='Title' value='' id='Title' style='color:#000;'/></span>")
                .$('#Title').val(photo.title)
                .appendTo(linksContainer);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than call `.val()` before the element is appended, just use the `value` attribute:

```
.append("<span><input type='text' name='Title' value='" + photo.title + "' id='Title' style='color:#000;'/></span>")
```

Also, ID's must be unique. (`Title` will be on multiple if this runs more than once)

Comment: Thanks tymeJV, that worked perfectly! I tried something similar, but could never get the javascript value to appear in the html. You solved this. No problem re non-unique ids.